# LINQ Help, data type of returned set

Tags: vb.net, linq, type-conversion

I am confused which data type to define for my variable which stores value returned by LINQ Statement.

Currently I am defining it as some data type but its generating error like: `""Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2""`

Sample Code:

```
Private BaseRateList = List (of BaseCat)
Private myBase As BaseCat = Nothing

'''In some other proc
myBase = From BaseRate In BaseRateList _
         Where BaseRate.UIN = 4 _
         Select BaseRate
```

Here i want myBase to hold the data which has UIN = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a single value. The options you probably want to consider are:

- [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx)
- [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx)
- [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx)
- [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx)

e.g.

```
myBase = (From BaseRate In BaseRateList _
          Where BaseRate.UIN = 4 _
          Select BaseRate).Single()
```

... depending on how you want it to behave if there are 0 or multiple matching values.

Or using the overload of `Single` (etc) which takes a predicate:

```
myBase = BaseRateList.Single(Function(baseRate) baseRate.UIN = 4)
```

Comment: yeah i do want single value. I tried as you said but it said Error: "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}"

Comment: @KoolKabin: Using which option? And what did the stack trace look like? Are you sure it wasn't BaseRateList that was Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Where condition by default returns IEnumberable(Baserates in your case). Take the first element of the returned list or try using

```
var baseRate = BaseRateList.Single(baseRate => baseRate.UIN == 4);
```

Comment: m poor in c# can it be translated in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query represents an expression that has not executed yet.  Right now your code is trying to put that query into a variable, which would have to be declared as IQueryable(Of BaseCat).  If you want to *execute* the query to get a result, you should use Aggregate instead of From to pick something out of the results of the query, or you should use ToList or ToArray to convert the results to a collection, or you should use First, FirstOrDefault, Single or SingleOrDefault function to pick one result from executing the query.

It's important to note the difference between the query itself and the results of executing the query.  If you put the query into a variable (IQueryable) you can expand on that query by then performing another query on that query (For example `Dim newQuery = From itm In myBase Where itm.MyDate <= Today`) and the query will still not execute until you actually force it to enumerate or pick a result from it using one of the above methods or something similar.